# How am I supposed to get the owner id of an aws market place ami?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, terraform

Im using terraform to get the official centos ami:

```
data "aws_ami" "centos" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["679593333241"] # Centos.org
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["CentOS Linux 7 x86_64 HVM EBS 1708_01-*"]
  }
}
```

I need the owner ID and the way I found it in this case was to aimlessly google until some article had it (they didn't say how they got it).

I can't find the owner ID on the ami's [market place page.](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00O7WM7QW)

If I launch the ami through it's market place page the ec2 instance it creates actually has my personal id set for the instance's "owner" field- so I can't launch an ec2 instance, check the owner and get it that way either.

Why is this so impossible to get? I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't necessarily *need* the owner ID but it is obviously a good idea to include to ensure you are getting the AMI you expect.

Given that you know the trusted owner up-front, the simple way to find the owner ID is to look in the AMIs table in the AWS console.

From the AWS console, navigate to *EC2 > Images > AMIs*. Select the *"Public Images"* filter from the dropdown on the left of the search box. You can then search for any AMI you want, and the *Owner* value is shown in the table:

[image]

Comment: For the latest version of terraform you do in fact need the owner ID. That being said, this was helpful in finding this previously-unneeded piece of information. Thank you!

Comment: I am interested in knowing how to find the friendly name for a given owner ID.

Comment: I never would have found that!

Answer (score 12):

If you'd like the use the AWS SDK; the easiest way to go about this is something like the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-0def3275 --region us-west-2
```

Of course, replace the region and AMI ID as appropriate.

If you'd like to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to then parse this; you could something like:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-0def3275 --region us-west-2 | jq -r .Images[0].OwnerId
```

Answer (score 1):

TJ is correct however, to use jq I had to add single quotes for it work:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-00dfe2c7ce89a450b --region us-east-2 | jq -r '.Images[0].OwnerId'
```